# Div inside php for

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Sorry for my syntaxis faults. But i haven't found the solution yet. The thing is that i have this code:

```
   <?php if ( get_option( 'phone' ) != '' ) : ?>
   <div class="phone"><?php echo do_shortcode( get_option( 'phone' ) ); ?>
   </div>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

And I want to make the same but inside a loop. Now I have this but it still not working:

```
   <?php
   $social = array("facebook", "twitter", "googleplus", "linkedin");

      for($i=0; $i<$longitud; $i++) {
         if ( get_option($social[$i]) != '' ) {
         echo'<div class=".$social[$i].">' . do_shortcode(get_option($social[$i])) . '</div>';
      }
      }

      ?>
```

Comment: Here's such a mess of output styles, please learn how to output data

Comment: I guess your favorite food is spaghetti.

Comment: Exactly as @u_mulder said. You are already in php code, then  reopen php code inside the echo, and then you re-echo inside the echo

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you stop copy/pasting stuff and take a few moments to read what the code you are trying to use does and how it works.

Everything starts somewhere and ends somewhere so:

```
<?php  {something_something} ?>
```

and:

```
echo {something_something} ;
```

are considered valid and this:

```
<?php echo <?php echo ?> <div> ?> 
{more php code}
```

is not valid

Answer (score 1):

You nerver used brackets[] for the array! and the concatenation operator to merge all variables and texts.

```
$social = array("facebook", "twitter", "googleplus", "linkedin");

for($i=0; $i<$longitud; $i++) {
    if ( get_option($social[$i]) != '' ) {
        echo'<div class="$social[$i]">' . do_shortcode(get_option($social[$i])) . '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain why, instead of just giving the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To use those arrays on the loop you need to use `[]` not `()`.

```
get_option($social[$i])
```

And those variables won't work since you used single quotes which does not interpolate variables inside, use double quotes instead:

```
'<div class="$social($i)">'
```

Modified code:

```
$social = array("facebook", "twitter", "googleplus", "linkedin");
for($i=0; $i<$longitud; $i++){
if ( get_option($social[$i] ) != '' ) {
        echo "<div class='$social[$i]'>" . do_shortcode(get_option($social[$i])) . '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not even parseable, so quotation is a secondary issue here.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath yeah switched the emphasis, should be the correct usage of arrays instead of those quotes

Comment: that's not a parse issue. "the" problem is `<?php`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath my god, i hope at least the OP got that

Answer (score 0):

Every variable inside ', it will treat as string so variable must be with in ". Of if you are using it under (') then it must be out side of it. So u
When you are using like `get_option('$social[$i]')`  then you must write like: `get_option('.$social[$i].')`.

Here you see i seprate this using (.) Dot , then it will be treated as variable. In your line of code every time when you are writting variable in side string then it should be seprated (variables) with dot(.), just before and after variable.